# Is WorkerManager a realiable way to implement alarm/reminder feature in the app?

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-workmanager

We notice that `AlarmManagerCompat` alone, isn't a reliable way to implement alarm/ reminder feature in our app, due to different `AlarmManager` behaviour in different version of OS. (For instance, Doze mode)

Initially, we plan to use Evernote's [android-job](https://github.com/evernote/android-job) library, to help us implement alarm/ reminder feature in our app.

However, along the way, we also notice that Google just release `WorkerManager`.

So far, `WorkerManager` works well for us, when we run some one-time background jobs (Almost immediate, with internet connectivity constraint) after the app quit.

We have plan to use `WorkerManager` to implement alarm/ reminder feature.

I was wondering, how reliable is `WorkerManager` to implement such feature? Has anyone try it out? We are targeting API 15 and above.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

WorkManager is not appropriate for anything that must fire at a specific time as jobs, including those used by WorkManager or android-job, will not fire while the device is dozing.

For exact timing, you should absolutely be using `AlarmManagerCompat` and specifically, [setExactAndAllowWhileIdle()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/AlarmManagerCompat.html#setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(android.app.AlarmManager,%20int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) which fires an alarm at exactly the specified time on all API levels.

As your exact timed alarm can and will happen while the device is dozing, your app should not require network connectivity to post your alarm/reminder notification. Ideally, the information should be in the `PendingIntent` itself and not even need any database fetch/etc.

Comment: "For exact timing, you should absolutely be using AlarmManagerCompat and specifically, setExactAndAllowWhileIdle() which fires an alarm at exactly the specified time on all API levels" -- only if the device is not in Doze mode or app standby, at which point the alarm becomes inexact (by up to 11 minutes IIRC).

Comment: @CommonsWare - the first alarm is still exact, they're just rate limited after that so it can appear as if the second is inexact

Comment: Ah, OK, I'll have to re-test that scenario -- thanks!

Comment: Thanks for input regarding WorkManager. My pass experience with `AlarmManager` is that, it isn't that reliable (Don't fire all the time). Based on feedback of community, https://old.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/82nbxf/android_alarms_notification_frustrated/ , they do have positive experience with Android Job from Evernote.

Comment: Android Job uses JobScheduler on newer versions of Android (it must, due to background restrictions). Since JobScheduler will never fire while the device is dozing, it would not be appropriate for something that needs to fire during doze (i.e., anything with an exact time).

Comment: `AlarmManager` is not user internally in `WorkManager`?

Comment: @PavelPoley - while WorkManager uses alarms on pre-API 23 devices when JobScheduler is not available/reliable, it does not use exact alarms nor alarms that fire in idle mode - both of which are required for something that needs to fire at a specific time.