# Periodic scheduler in OREO and Nougat Device

Tags: android, android-notifications

We have to show notification at 11 Pm night everyday.We have used JobSchedular for this but it does not work when we kill my application.Please share some workaround for this task which can solve this problem.i just want to do like that Alarm Manager do in the previous version.

Thanks,
Sumit

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50546739/is-workermanager-a-realiable-way-to-implement-alarm-reminder-feature-in-the-app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Evernote-Jobs library as it has DailyJob built in, I think it's best fit for ur use case, as you need to show notification at 11 everyday.

Look here - [Evernote-Jobs](https://github.com/evernote/android-job/wiki/FAQ)

As of now in 2019, you can also use work manager library as it's pretty stable now.